# Error in finding sum of $1\cdot 2+3\cdot 4+ \cdots \text{to}\space n\space \text{terms}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs

To find sum of the series $1\cdot 2+3\cdot 4+ \cdots \text{to}\space n\space \text{terms}$
My approach,
Let S=$1^2+2^2+3^2 + \cdots +n^2$
If $n$ is even
S=$(1-2)^2+(3-4)^2+ \cdots +[(n-1)-n]^2+2(1 \cdot 2+3 \cdot 4+5 \cdot 6+ \cdots \text{to}\space \dfrac{n}{2}\space \text{terms})$
=$\frac{n}2+2(1 \cdot 2+3 \cdot 4+5 \cdot 6+ \cdots \text{to}\space \dfrac{n}{2}\space \text{terms})$
And we know,
$$S=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$
Therefore,$$2(1 \cdot 2+3 \cdot 4+5 \cdot 6+ \cdots \text{to}\space \frac{n}2\space \text{terms}) =\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6-\frac{n}2$$
or $$2(1 \cdot 2+3 \cdot 4+5 \cdot 6+ \cdots \text{to}\space \frac{n}2\space \text{terms})=\frac{n}2.\frac{2n^2+3n-2}3$$
or $$(1 \cdot 2+3 \cdot 4+5 \cdot 6+ \cdots \text{to}\space \frac{n}2\space \text{terms})=\frac{n(n+2)(2n-1)}{24}$$
But, this is the sum of $\dfrac{n}{2}$ terms. To get sum of $n$ terms, we replace $n$ by $2n$
Thus,
$$(1 \cdot 2+3 \cdot 4+5 \cdot 6+ \cdots \text{to}\space n\space \text{terms})=\frac{n(n+1)(4n-1)}6$$
So, if input of $n$ is even result should be correct,
if $n=2$, sum (from formula) = $7$
However, actual sum is $14$ (=$1 \cdot 2+3 \cdot 4$).
What is the error in the above approach?
**EDIT**: I rechecked my calculations and also have written the steps but still the answer isn't coming right. Please tell in which step the problem lies.
Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: You have several errors. If you want to find the sum for even $n$, then substitute $n=2k$ and then calculate more accurately.

Comment: You are making a mistake in the 'combining the above results' part. Your sum of $\frac{n}{2}$ terms is equal to $\frac{1}{2} (S - \frac{n}{2})$, and this is not equal to $\frac{n(n+2)(2n-1)}{8}$.

Comment: @njguliyev I have correctly assummed $n$ is even because only then 
can I pair L.H.S.

Comment: Your first error is "... to $n/2$ terms". That is why I suggest you to start with the substitution $n = 2k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} - \frac{n}{2} = \frac{n}{2}\frac{2n^{2} + 3n - 2}{3}$$ and if you divide this expression by $2$ you are supposed to get $$\frac{n(n + 2)(2n - 1)}{12}$$ but you get mistakenly $$\frac{n(n + 2)(2n - 1)}{24}$$ This is the source of error. If you fix this problem you will get the right formula $$(1\cdot 2) + (2\cdot 4) + \cdots + \{(2n - 1)\cdot (2n)\} = \frac{n(n + 1)(4n - 1)}{3}$$

Comment: I am still surprised how you missed such a simple calculation mistake even after a recheck. The error should also have been obvious because you were getting answers which were half the correct value ($7$ instead of $14$). But your approach is right.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{m=1}^n (2m-1)(2m) = \frac{1}{3}n(n+1)(4n-1)$$

Comment: But MathGod's question is what is their error, not what is the actual formula. I would give 1/2 a vote if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting approach and it will work for all values of n if you do it right.

The sum of  first n terms in the sequence 1.2 + 3.4 + ... is calculated by the taking first sum of **2n terms of the sum of squares sequence (S in your case)**, subtracting n from it and taking the half.

say n = 2 sum of first 4 squares is 30 subtract 2 and take half 14.

for n = 3 sum of first 6 squares is 91 subtract 2 and take half 44.

and so on.

Your method works, however when you write "Combining the above results, we get," there you have done a **calculation mistake**.

There are simpler ways of doing the problem, however I like your approach.